# Make a bot wait for some time before continuing the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there any way to make a bot wait for some time (for example 5 seconds) before continuing the code? I need something like:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => { 
message.channel.send('1st message')
wait(5000)
message.channel.send('2nd message')
wait(5000) 
message.channel.send('3rd message')
})
```

I tried using `setInterval`, like many people suggest, but that doesn't seem to be a solution for me.
Also I can't use `await setTimeout(time)` because of `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules` and `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received 5000`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: setInterval would be involved in any answer in some fashion, if you share your usage maybe we can figure out the issue.

Comment: @SvenEberth If I understood answer you suggested correctly, it's not working for me, even tho I have up-to-date node.js version! (`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received 5000`)

Comment: @DanOswalt basically I need to send few messages with some short delay between them

Comment: function doThing() { console.log('hi') }

setInterval( doThing, 5000);

this doesn't work?

Comment: @DanOswalt as I said, I need to send few messages (and yes, more than 2), and I don't want to use a lot of `setInterval`s because it looks messy in code, and for some reason I have to wait longer than time I set in code

Comment: setTimeout or setInterval is going to either be in your code or abstracted out somewhere else. sounds like you want something like in the top comment if the goal is to use setTimeout in a synchronous-looking manner with async/await.

Comment: You need to share some more details. We don't know how you send the messages. In your question you asked how to wait between these two `console.log`s. You can use the `setTimeout` function for that, there are a lot of examples and [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) for this... Maybe you can use a loop or a callback to handle multiple delays for your messages?

Answer (score 2):

You can [promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) `setTimeout` with Node's [Util](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html) library. Then make the `messageCreate` callback asynchronous.

```js
const wait = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);

client.on('messageCreate', async message => { 
   message.channel.send('1st message')
   await wait(5000)
   
   message.channel.send('2nd message')
   await wait(5000) 
   
   message.channel.send('3rd message')
})
```