# How do I add a delay between sending messages discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Here is the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client()
const KeepClientOn = require('./KeepClientOn.js')

client.on("message", function(message) {
message.reply('my message');
})

client.login('client login')
```

after the message is replied I want there to be a 5 minute delay before it can reply again BUT not   reply to any messages sent before then. Here is pretty much what I want:
Me: hi
Bot: my message
Me (2 minutes later): hi again
Bot: (Sends nothing)
5 minutes later:
Me: Hello once again
Bot: my message

(Sorry for so much stuff)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a bot wait for some time before continuing the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69578474/make-a-bot-wait-for-some-time-before-continuing-the-code)

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask]. What have you tried?

Comment: The different reply things are supposed to be on new lines sorry

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft I tried that but got an error

Comment: @Tamthejam so what is the error...?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I have two solutions for you.

### 1# Wait for some time then execute a piece of code

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), it's a javascript function who only needs two arguments. The first one is the function who's going to get executed after a certain timeout and the second one is how much milliseconds does you code need to wait before doing that function.

```js
message.channel.send('Hi!')
setTimeout(function(){
message.channel.send('Hi again.. !')
},1000 * 10) // 1000 milliseconds multiplied by 10, therefore 10 second.
```

### 2# Wait for some time then execute the rest of the code

This one is pretty similar to the one before but this time you won't put your code on a function. You can just create a function like so :

```js
let sleep = async (ms) => await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r,ms));
```

And here you have a sleep function, it will freeze your current code for x milliseconds then continue as if nothing happens,

```js
let sleep = async (ms) => await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r,ms));
message.channel.send('Going to sleep!')
await sleep(2000)
message.channel.send("I'm awake!!")
```

Comment: That gave me the following error:
await sleep(60000)
^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: The code looks like this:
    client.on("message", function(message) {
    let sleep = async (ms) => await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r,ms));
    message.reply('My message');
    await sleep(60000)
    })

Comment: @Tamthejam you need to make the function async, replace `function` with `async function` and it should work